# What is the meaning and use of the word 'Duco'?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning

I want to confirm my understanding of the word `duco`.

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duco), it is a third conjugation, irregular short imperative. The examples are:

1. I lead, guide
2. I draw, pull
3. I think, consider
4. I prolong

I understand it is therefore singular, present and first person.

Why is it irregular? The present infinitive is `ducere` and regular third conjugations have infinitives ending in '-ere'?

Please could someone provide an example of `duco` being used in a valid sentence?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Do you want an example of the irregular imperative *duc* or any example whatsoever with that verb?

Comment: Any example with the verb 'Duco' would be very much appreciated. I'm not a linguist, just considering the word duco with the 'o' ending for use in the name of an art project. Wanted to verify my basic understanding of what it meant.

Comment: But also—if the examples the answers offer you *don't* fit with your basic understanding, leave a comment to that effect. *Duco* is a word that can be used in a lot of different ways to mean a lot of different things, so there may still be hope.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and for the great feedback, very helpful. I read that 'duco' may refer more to the leadership of an army rather than the 'art of leadership'. What are your thoughts on this? The word 'educo' was put forward as an alternative meaning I teach or I stimulate mental growth; would you agree?

Comment: For a short answer, "educo" means something like "bring up," as in "bring up children." It sounds a little bit like you're looking for something that has more to do with inspiration or charisma. Why don't you tell us (in a separate question) about your project in a little more detail and we'll see how we can help?

Comment: Thanks, new question posted: http://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/581/does-duco-refer-to-the-art-of-leadership

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Latin a verb has several forms.
In Wiktionary you can click the little "More" button to the right of "Conjugation of duco" under the title "Inflection".
There you will notice that *duco* is only one of the many forms.

The word *duco* means "I lead" (let me choose only one from the list of translations to keep things simple).
The word *ducere* means "to lead".
This verb is listed in dictionaries as *duco* or *ducere*.
There are different forms for different persons, tenses and such.

Here is a simple use example: *Te duco si sequi vis*. "I lead you if you want to follow."

For a verb like this (third conjugation), you would expect the second person singular present imperative to be *duce* but it is *duc*.
There is no obvious reason why it is irregular.
Only some of the most common verbs have an irregular imperative like this: *dicere* (to say), *ducere* (to lead), *facere* (to do) and *ferre* (to carry).

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and for the great feedback, very helpful. I read that 'duco' may refer more to the leadership of an army rather than the 'art of leadership'. What are your thoughts on this? The word 'educo' was put forward as an alternative meaning I teach or I stimulate mental growth; would you agree?

Comment: @Pete those are two separate questions. Ask them as two separate questions, and you'll get a better answer.

Comment: @Pete, you are welcome! I wrote an answer to your follow-up question, but it's too long for a comment. As QPaysTaxes suggests, it is better to ask new questions as separate questions. Also, since you have already received several answers, please do not edit this question too much to invalidate them. It often works best to ask a separate follow-up separately, unless it can be answered in a comment (in a couple of sentences).

Comment: New question posted: http://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/581/does-duco-refer-to-the-art-of-leadership

Answer (score 6):

*Duco* is regular in the indicative and subjunctive moods but irregular in the imperative mood.

So you might say, using the indicative,

> Dido Æneam in aulam ducit.
>   Dido leads Æneas into the palace.

If *duco* took a regular imperative, the singular second-person imperative would be *duce*. However, since it doesn't, the singular second-person imperative is *duc*.

So if you were Æneas, you might say

> Dido! Me in aulam duc!
>   Dido! Lead me into the palace!

Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 3):

There isn't much more to add to Joel's and Joonas' posts, but I just wanted to make an additional note about the irregular imperatives. First, *ducere*, *dicere*, and *facere* are only irregular in the imperative singular: *duc*, *dic*, *fac*, but are fully regular in the imperative plural: *ducite*, *dicite*, *facite*.

*Ferre*, however, is still irregular in the plural, *ferte* instead of **ferite*. It's also irregular in the 2nd/3rd-sing-ind-act (*fers*/*fert*), 2nd-pl-ind-act (*fertis*), and 2nd/3rd-sing-ind-pass (*ferris*/*fertur*).

The verbs *nolle* and *esse* also have irregular imperatives, which is expected since they're fully irregular verbs: s. *noli*, s. *es*, and pl. *este*. *Ire* is surprisingly regular in the imperative.